# Are ChannelPipeline modifications guaranteed to have immediate effect when made from a non-Netty thread?

Tags: java, netty

I start 2 `Channel` instances on the same machine: first of them sends to the second, and vice versa.

Then I do the following:

```
channel2.pipeline().addAfter(OutboundEncoder.NAME, OutgoingAcknowledgementSilencer.NAME, ackSilencer);

channel1.writeAndFlush(message);
```

This code is executed in a `main` thread (so not a Netty thread, for sure).

Most of the time, this works as I expect it to work: when the message sent in the second line arrives, the receiving pipeline (of `channel2`) behaves as if it had that `ackSilencer` added. But very rarely, I observe that the pipeline of `channel2` does not call that handler added on line 1.

Javadoc of `ChannelPipeline` at https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelPipeline.html says the following:

> A ChannelHandler can be added or removed at any time because a ChannelPipeline is thread safe. For example, you can insert an encryption handler when sensitive information is about to be exchanged, and remove it after the exchange.

But is there a guarantee that such an insertion have an *immediate* effect when it's done from another thread (not an event loop thread)?

Answer (score 0):

I added the following to the handler:

```
final CountDownLatch addedLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

@Override
public void handlerAdded(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    super.handlerAdded(ctx);

    addedLatch.countDown();
}
```

and then I also added an await for the method to be called:

```
channel2.pipeline().addAfter(OutboundEncoder.NAME, OutgoingAcknowledgementSilencer.NAME, ackSilencer);
ackSilencer.addedLatch.await(1, SECONDS);
channel1.writeAndFlush(message);
```

This seems to work as we explicitly await for the addition to happen.

Another approach that worked was adding the handler in the corresponding evnet loop explicitly and then using a `CountDownLatch` like this:

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1)
channel2.eventLoop().execute(() -> {
    channel2.pipeline().addAfter(OutboundEncoder.NAME, OutgoingAcknowledgementSilencer.NAME, ackSilencer);
    latch.countDown();
});
latch.await(1, SECONDS);
channel1.writeAndFlush(message);
```

But this seems to do by hand what is made by Netty itself.